# Are all of the characteristics of elementary particles essentially symmetry differences?

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, big-bang, symmetry-breaking, elementary-particles

I am trying to get a better conceptual grasp on the "splitting" of the fundamental forces at the beginning of the universe.

The first force to separate was the gravitational force. Am I correct in understanding that, prior to gravity's split, everything was "gravitationally symmetrical?" Meaning that any values of gravitational push or pull were equal.

Likewise, were all particles symmetrical as far as the strong force, prior to the separation of the strong force? And only upon the splitting-off of the strong force did some particles acquire color charge?

Likewise, can the split of the electromagnetic force be said to have broken an electromagnetic symmetry, where particles's electromagnetic charges were meaningless and could be said to be effectively equal..

My question is whether or not this is a conceptual error or if it is accurate.

I am very interested in understanding whether the symmetry-breaking events can also be viewed as speciation-events of the particles of the standard model.